# Casting object to an interface return null

Tags: c#, interface, casting

I have an object from a class which returns an interface. but when I cast the object to that interface it returns null. what is the problem?

```
public partial class CompanyConfigurations : SgConfigurationControl, `IWizardControl`

CompanyConfigurations c
c as IWizardControl
```

Comment: Do you know what interface are?

Comment: Please try to post a complete example. At the moment we have a fragment of a class declaration then immediately jump to some code that can only exist within a method.

Comment: @Tinwor : absolutely YES!

Comment: So please post the code also we cannot help you

Comment: Looks as you haven't create the instance: `CompanyConfigurations c = new CompanyConfigurations();`

Comment: If you want a serious answer then post some serious code.

Comment: The problem were solved. it was my error

Answer (score 7):

The `as` operator returns null if the instance you want to cast, does not implement the specified interface, or does not inherit from the specified base class.

It's all clearly stated in MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx

Offcourse, if the instance that you want to cast is not assigned to an instance of a class (in other words, if the variable is null, then casting the variable using the `as` operator will return null as well offcourse.

Comment: I implement IWizard methods in CompanyConfigurations. what else should I do?